# Parsing Help in Python

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

Can someone help me parse this? I am having a great deal of trouble. I am parsing information from this [site](https://interactive.web.insurance.ca.gov/survey/survey?type=homeownerSurvey&event=HOMEOWNERS).

Here are a few lines of code which pull data from a table with 2 titles and 4 values:

```
for x in soup.findAll(attrs={'valign':'top'}):
                print(x.contents)
                make_list = x.contents
                print(make_list[1]) #trying to select one of the values on the list.
```

When I try to print it with the `make_list[1]` line, it gets an error. However, if I pull out the last 2 lines, I get the html that i wanted in list format, but I can't seem to separate the individual ones or filter them (to take out the html tags). Can anybody help?

Here is a sample of the output, I want to get specific in here. I'm not sure of the proper regular expressions:

```
 ['\n', <td align="left">Western Mutual/Residence <a href="http://interactive.web.insurance.ca.gov/companyprofile/companyprofile?event=companyProfile&amp;doFunction=getCompanyProfile&amp;eid=3303"><small>(Info)</small></a></td>, '\n', <td align="left"><div align="right">           355</div></td>, '\n', <td align="left"><div align="right">250</div></td>, '\n', <td align="left"> </td>, '\n', <td align="left">Western Mutual/Residence <a href="http://interactive.web.insurance.ca.gov/companyprofile/companyprofile?event=companyProfile&amp;doFunction=getCompanyProfile&amp;eid=3303"><small>(Info)</small></a></td>, '\n', <td align="left"><div align="right">           320</div></td>, '\n', <td align="left"><div align="right">500</div></td>, '\n']
```

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: "it gets an error". What's the error?

Comment: @Kevin IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @VigneshKalai Sheet 1 - Company name : Western Mutual/Residence Premium:  355 Deductible: 250

Sheet 2 - Company name: Western Mutual/ Residence Premium:320 Deductible: 500 

something like that

Comment: Is "IndexError" the _only_ output you get? Or does it successfully print some contents before crashing? Do you think this error is occurring on the first iteration of the loop, or later?

Comment: Oh no I've been able to play around with the code and I can usually come pretty close to what I want, except that for some of the values in the table say N/A and the only regex I know to find the "premium price" or "deductible" values is r'\d{1,10}' or stuff of that sort, and it messes up because some values say N/A and N/A is not a number so it would make my results inaccurate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to parse the results from that website, the following should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = ....add your html....
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
rows = []
tables = soup.find_all('table')
t2 = None

# Find the second from last table
for t3 in tables:
    t1, t2 = t2, t3

for row in t1.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
    cols = [col.text.strip() for col in cols]
    rows.append(cols)

# Collate the two columns
data = [cols[0:3] for cols in rows]
data.extend([cols[4:7] for cols in rows[1:]])

for row in data:
    print "{:40}  {:15} {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

This gives me output looking like:

```
Company Name                              Annual Premium  Deductible
AAA (Interinsurance Exchange) (Info)      N/A             250
Allstate (Info)                           315             250
American Modern (Info)                    N/A             250
Amica Mutual (Info)                       259             250
Bankers Standard (Info)                   N/A             250
California Capital  (Info)                160             250
Century National (Info)                   N/A             250
.....
```

**How does it work?**

As the webpage is primarily displaying a table, this is what we need to find, so the first step is to get a list of tables.

The site has used tables for a number of sections. The chances are the structure of the page will remain constant between requests at least.

The table we need is almost the last on the page (but not the very last) so I decided to iterate through the available tables and pick the second from last. `t1` `t2` `t3` is just a work around to keep the last values whilst iterating.

From here an HTML table usually has a fairly standard structure, `TR` and `TD`. This one also used a `TH` for the header row. Using this `table` BeautifulSoup then allows us to enumerate all the rows.

With each row we can then find all of the columns. If you print what is returned, you will see all of the entries for each row, you can then see which indexes are needed to slice it up.

They have displayed the output in two column groups, with a blank column in the middle. I build two lists that extract the two groups of columns and then attach the second group to the bottom of the first group for display.

Comment: OMG  thank you I will try that out...  that is totally different from what I had in mind... but I don't understand how do you find t1, t2, t3 inside the webpage? How did you find those so that I could know for future tables? Thank you I will try this though and let you know how it works :)

Comment: And how did you know to look for specifically 'td' and 'th'? What I've been doing is right clicking and inspecting element and trying to look and make sense of that code lol.

Comment: Like how are you getting the numbers 0,3, 4, 7, 40, 15? Lol sorry to bother you by asking... but thank you also!

Comment: I have added an explanation as to the approach that was used to solve the problem. Hopefully you find this useful. You do need to have a grasp of HTML in order to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: thank you for your help! By inspecting the elemtn I can see that It seems that they contained everything inside the <tbody> </tbody> tags. the TH is the header, you are right.... but what is the difference between TR and TD? It seems that TD is being used to the the numbers only, and TR for the entire row. Am I looking at things the wrong way, or is this the right way to interpret the source code of a table? 

Sorry for the newbieness, I am still learning. Again I thank you for helping me, I will take this lesson to heart. Will let you know how it looks later!

Comment: I think the following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) should help to explain things a bit.

Comment: I guess layman terms is... the rows are divided using <tr> as seen in inspect element? And then each row divides into individual columns using <td> right? and each new set of <tr>'s gives me 5 values of <td>'s? (1 title and 4 numbers) Sorry for the confusion :(

Comment: Exactly, that is how HTML structures a table.

Comment: Thank you sir! I think I understand the problem and will try to move forward from here :) I just saw your reply and that explained everything!!

Comment: God Bless You kind sir

Comment: Mr Martin Evans, 

I understand what you are doing down to the last part, where you put {:40} {:15}. I get that you are trying to replace those with the values of row 0 1 and 2, but why specifically are you using the numbers 40 and 15? where do i get this number from inside the inspect element?

Comment: They are simply padding the output to 40 characters and 15 characters. Try changing the values to say 10 and you will see the need.